# Golang simple http file server concurrent connections limitation on Windows

Tags: go, concurrency, fileserver

I am trying to create a fairly simple http file server in Go.  Ideally, it should be able to support multiple concurrent file downloads from 2 to 20 clients simultaneously.

I have tried several different approaches including the using the "net/http" and "gorilla" libraries with the same unsuccessful results:  the first two clients connect and begin downloading the file normally.  Any additional connections fail until one of the first two completes.

Is there a maximum number of concurrent connections / downloads of the same file and can this be increased?

- Operating system: Windows 10 Enterprise - max 2 concurrent
- Operating system: Ubuntu 22.04 - unknown max, but at least 15
- Operating system: Raspbian v11 - unknown max, but at least 15

Very simplified code example below:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    log.Printf("\nListening... [:80]")

    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")))

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":80", mux); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not start server: \n %v", err)
    }

}
```

Comment: The maximum is system dependent, as is how you would change that. 2-20 is trivial, so you would ned to show a [mre] of the problem for anyone to offer a specific answer.

Comment: Be sure any concurrent clients are properly closing the body response of any web calls. Without this the server will not be able to do connection reuse & resources will eventually became exhausted as new unclosed connections pile up.

Comment: @JimB added detail that original test machine is Win10 Enterprise.  Confirmed Unbuntu 22.04 supports at least 6 concurrent connections.  On Win10 can this limitation be increased?

Comment: @Peter: you need to provide more info or a working example. When I say that you can increase the maximum, I mean starting in the thousands. If you cannot handle 2-20 concurrent connections then there is something else going on.

Comment: @JimB Thank you for assisting - the code I included is a working example I think?  The same code on Win10 does not allow more than 2 concurrent connections while on Ubuntu 22.04 I was able to have 15 concurrent downloads.  As you suggested, it appears to be OS specific.  Can this be modified for Win10?